# Using UrlImage causes bad quality scaled image

Tags: java, codenameone

I am trying to create an app using codename one that uses a RESTful web service to download details to be displayed including an image url.

I think what I need is ScaleImageButton, the purpose of which is to have a list of items to be clicked to display more information (so several ScaleImageButtons).

The code I am currently using to create the button is as follows:

```
java.util.List<String> splitImage = tokenize(url, '/');
EncodedImage placeholder = FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_SAVE, btnStyle.getUnselectedStyle()).toEncodedImage();
URLImage image = URLImage.createToStorage(placeholder, splitImage.get(splitImage.size() - 1), url, URLImage.RESIZE_SCALE_TO_FILL);
ScaleImageButton btn = new ScaleImageButton(image);
btn.setBackgroundType(Style.BACKGROUND_IMAGE_SCALED_FILL);
```

The background image of this button is of very poor quality (a few millimetres per pixel) even though the image displays in the larger browser window.

How can I have the image fill the background but also keep its quality?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is downloading an image which is the size of your `placeholder` and scaling it up by applying it to a `ScaleImageButton`, instead of downloading an image of the right size.

Be sure that your placeholder image is of the right size before using it to download the actual image.

For instance:

```
//half the size of device width image
EncodedImage placeholder = FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_SAVE, btnStyle.getUnselectedStyle(), CN.getDisplayWidth() / 2).toEncodedImage();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I have done that the image is still bad quality but it is now making the button the same size as the image whereas the background image was only a portion of the image (cropped to fit the button).

Comment: Are you using Windows, Mac or Linux computer?

Comment: I am using a Mac but I have also built the app and tried it on my iPhone and it has the same results.

Comment: Because the images are cached once downloaded. On your iPhone, you will have to delete the previous app to remove its cached images before re-installing. On Mac, you can do the same by going to your Hard-Drive.

Comment: I'm new to Mac, where are they located on the hard drive?

Comment: I have cleared it and that has solved the pixelation problem but now the image is making the button too big, I would like it so the background image is cropped like the image in the question. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you sketch and post what you're trying to achieve or post the UI design? Then I will be able to assist you better. You can blur out sensitive information.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153042/discussion-between-kieran-jennings-and-diamond).